# Were the nations(Gentiles) judged on account of their physical uncircumcision in Jeremiah 9:25-26?

Tags: law, jeremiah, circumcision

Jeremiah 9:25 KJV

> Behold, the days come, saith the LORD, that I will punish all them which are circumcised with the uncircumcised;  26 Egypt, and Judah, and Edom, and the children of Ammon, and Moab, and all that are in the utmost corners, that dwell in the wilderness:  ***for all these nations are uncircumcised, and all the house of Israel are uncircumcised in the heart***

There seems to be a clear distinction between the physical uncircumcised(Gentiles) and those who are uncircumcised in heart(Israel) in the above texts.The Israelites are judged on account of

*abandoning the law

*have not obeyed the voice of God

*followed stubbornness of their hearts

*they speak lies

*deceiving their neighbours

whilst not much is said of the transgression of Gentiles other than being lumped together with Israelites.

Were the nations charged on account of their physical uncircumcision?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text seems to show that the judgment of God was impartial. He was judging the Gentile nations equally alongside the nation of Israel. The word 'circumcision' was being used to indicate a sign of God's covenant, and, in this respect, all the Gentile nations (who never were brought into covenant with God, thus were not called to be circumcised) were now on a par with the nation of Israel which had broken its covenant with God.

From God's point of view, Israel was not circumcised in the way that mattered to God - their hearts were unclean. Their hearts were not spiritually 'circumcised' so they might as well have been as uncircumcised physically as were the Gentile nations. They were all going to be judged by God, equally, as not being in covenant relationship with him.

For the nation of Israel, this was the most horrible indictment possible - to be likened to uncircumcised Gentiles, for God had called them out of pagan Egypt to be a people for his name, and circumcision was the sign of that holy nationhood. But because they had violated that holy covenant, doing things the uncircumcised pagans did, God was going to judge them all alike.

This was proof of the truth of verse 24, that to understand, know, and glory in the God of Israel was to acknowledge him to be "the Lord which exercise loving-kindness, judgment, and righteousness". Further, that his people must carry out those things themselves - otherwise they would be rightly judged by God as unclean, having broken his covenant.

**The answer to your question** is that the nations were judged as being unclean to God, as are all people outside of his covenant, or as are all those in his covenant who then violate it. The language of circumcision relates to covenant, here, not to a physical condition of the men in a nation.

Answer (score 2):

In short - no, God didn't judge the Gentiles because of a physical characteristic.

Jeremiah is saying that because the people of God had turned their hearts against God, they will be punished along with everyone else, as if they were not people of God.

> I will punish all them which are circumcised with the uncircumcised

It's a prophetic word meant to bring home the horrible situation the Israelites had put themselves in. The people of Israel were circumcised (carried the physical symbol) but their heart and behavior demonstrated that their circumcision was a lie.

The physical uncircumcision of the Gentiles is a symbol of the condition of their heart - is the heart in covenant or out of covenant, just as circumcision was supposed to be a sign or symbol that the person was in covenant with God.

> Genesis 17:9 Then God said to Abraham, “As for you, you must keep my covenant, you and your descendants after you for the generations to come. 10 This is my covenant with you and your descendants after you, the covenant you are to keep: Every male among you shall be circumcised. 11 You are to undergo circumcision, and **it will be the sign of the covenant between me and you**

The condition of the heart (Gentile or Jewish) bears the fruit of it's condition in relationship with God - rebellion against God or obedience to God.
God does not judge people by their physical characteristics but by the condition of their heart.

One example of this truth is demonstrated in the person of Job who lived before Judaism existed and of whom God said:

> Job 1:8 Then the Lord said to Satan, “Have you considered my servant Job? There is no one on earth like him; he is blameless and upright, a man who fears God and shuns evil.”